# Is there such a thing as an RF CMOS pdk?

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, cmos

In [this](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00445302/document) PhD thesis (page 10) about some dust particle detector that was based on an RF chip , we can read

> " Since this thesis was the first attempt in this way, there were not
> any primary experiences, or guide lines or even predefined parameters
> and characteristics for the RF front end. Due to cost considerations
> and some other limitations, global purpose CMOS process was used,
> instead of ***RF CMOS process*** and this was source of many
> challenges in our work. Actually we were obliged to develop all of the
> required modeling and design procedure for passive elements, as well
> as the proper parasitic models for active devices. "

This got me wondering about the PDKs the foundries provide. Are the PDKs used for digital/VLSI/ASIC design different from those used for RF design? What are the main differences, if any? For example, I have the tsmc 0.13u pdk (it's called tsmc13rf), will it be suitable for designing RFICs? As a side note, I can see spiral inductors and MIM caps among the components listed in the library of this pdk.

Many thanks.

Comment: All PDK's can be used for mixed-signal analog, digital,RF but I expect the limitations for 130nm will be greater than 65 nm or 8 nm or 5 nm.  This is because all digital semiconductors have analog RF properties.

Comment: PDK != foundry process. If a foundry provides a process with suitable specifications for RFICs, then it'd be prudent to put in the effort to include any useful components in a design kit for that process to help their customers design products and taping out mask sets to buy wafers using said process. No reason to shut down another source of revenue. The only "difference" I could think of is whether or not the PDK includes elements to facilitate EM simulation.